# Android. Why E/JavaBinder: FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION?

Tags: java, android, performance

I have read a lot of posts about this error, most of them regarding managing an image.

But I'm getting this error when I stop the app (put in background), so should be regarding data in memory...

I'm not doing anything in onStop() of my fragment and activity.

I have checked onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) and the bundle is empty... ¿?

I have 5 ArrayList of objects and making tests I realized that if I don't have the biggest one the error is not thrown.

My app is going to has more data than now it has, so it is a problem.

Could anyone explain me about why I'm getting this and how I have to handle this??

Error:

```
01-25 13:51:09.272 4940-4940/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 539984)

--------- beginning of crash
01-25 13:51:09.281 4940-4940/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher, PID: 4940
  java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 539984 bytes
      at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4039)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
   Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 539984 bytes
      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:617)
      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3632)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4031)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
01-25 13:51:09.286 1795-5775/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stop the app"? "Could anyone explain me about why I'm getting this" -- usually, this comes from either putting too much data in the saved instance state `Bundle` or by passing too much data in extras on an `Intent` (e.g., for `startActivity()`).

Comment: Sorry im going to explain it better

Comment: I have checked onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) and the bundle is empty. How android manages it?

Answer (score 9):

You are moving too much data through a binder interface. This can happen if using a custom binder interface and passing large object, or if you are attaching extras to an `Intent` which a very large (or lots of objects so the size adds up.) This could be when sending an `Intent` or when receiving a result. Binder is used for any kind of cross process communication in Android and still is used when starting activities in the same app. Binder has a limited sized buffer internally, so large transactions can cause failures like this.

Rather than place your data into the `Intent`directly, or pass it directly to a binder based method call, pass a reference of some kind and the receiver can access the dates using the reference. For example, send an id for the data stored in a DB or similar mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was an infinite loop for a method (recursive) which saturated the stack.

Comment: An infinite while loop was the cause for us